# Ode with step function in the right-hand-side

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE:
$$\dot{X}(t,x)=F(X(t,x))$$
where $F(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $-1$ if $x<0$.
How to treat this discontinuous right-hand-side?

Comment: Why should you 'treat' this? $F$ is not defined if $x=0$! You can combine partial solutions as you like to find a solution on $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$

Comment: What do you mean with partial solution?

Comment: I can recommend you Filippov's book (see Example 2 on p.1 there) http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-015-7793-9 . Of course the classical solutions don't exist, since you have discontinuity of the first derivative at $t=0$. Hence, you need to generalize properly the conception of a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by a solution? Do you have any initial conditions?